# Reload web page - browser "back" button ( HTML/JSP)

Tags: javascript, jsp, http, servlets

I have a small issue. In my web application I use jsp forms.

There is a form and it's data gets stored in a database when user submit the form. Upon a successful submission, user is redirected to a confirmation page.

However, when the user press the "back" button of the browser, user is redirected to the previous form.(No server side interaction/No updated data from the database) And when the user press submit,that data is also saved in DB. Since this is an account related application, this behavior is not acceptable.

**My question is, is there a way to prevent this behavior?**

Comment: You can't really stop the user from going to the page again... You could insert a unique ID into the page and check if that ID was submitted before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created a solution using javascript based on Luca's idea and it worked.Now when user press the back button, form is filled with the updated and latest data from database.

```
<input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">
    <script type="text/javascript">

           onload=function(){
               var e=document.getElementById("refreshed");
               if(e.value=="no")e.value="yes";
               else{e.value="no";location.reload();}
           }

    </script>
```

Thanks :)